# Отображение загрузки файла WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Есть WebMethod который принимает html и помещает в pdf файл(в темп юзера). Файл формируется, сохраняется, но это происходит незаметно для пользователя(не показывается строка загрузки файла и тд). `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader()` из под WebMethod не работает я так понимаю.

Кто-то может подсказать как быть в таком случае.

**UPD:**

1. $.post из js отправляем на сервер html
2. Создаем PDF файл в темп папке пользователя
3. После в js создаем ссылку, кликаем, возвращаемся за ответом ввиде загрузки файла.

JS:

```
   $.post('DownloadFile.aspx', { HTMLString: str }, function (result) {       
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = 'DownloadFile.aspx';
        a.target = '_self';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);    
    });
```

DownloadFile.aspx:

```
 const string fileName = "__temp.pdf";      
 string filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + fileName;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string HTMLString = Request.Form["HTMLString"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HTMLString))
        {
            converttopdf(HTMLString);                                                          
        }
        else
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                               "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();   
        }
    }

    public void converttopdf(string html)
    {       
            string filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + "_temp.pdf";                                                                                       
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);                

            document.Open();

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                  writer, document, reader
                );
            document.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Отправить файл на скачивание так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server

Comment: у меня WebMethod и данные формируются в js. Мне не подходит такое решение.

Comment: Тогда не понятно к чему `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader` ведь его нету в js. Тогда не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: Клиент браузера скрытно сохранить файл в любое место не даст (такие дыры находили и позатыкали). Есть некоторые "приколы" которые позволяют сохранять данные в localStorage или mso-storage, но явно не декларируется что файл будет сохранён в конкретное место.

Comment: nick_n_a, спасибо за комментарий. Суть в том, что когда юзер нажмет ссылку, js сформирует данные и отправит в WebMethod, где в свою очередь состряпается pdf файл и сохранится в темп юзера, **но он этого не увидит**. Без js(ajax) и с `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader` юзер бы увидил загрузку файла, нажал бы открыть и посмотрел содержимое.

Comment: Теперь ясно. Тогда вам вместо "скачивания файла" нужно сделать post/get запрос к сайту напрямую (если нужна серверная ссылка, получить из ajax ссылку), за тем либо сделать location.href="ссылка", либо создать a href=ссылка (+ target=_clear илим поиграться с target) и сделать по ней клик. После этого начнётся скачивание файла. Для того что б браузер не светил "белую" страницу, нужно в хедерах сразу указать Content-Length и Content-Type.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за совет, попробую разобраться) но если есть примерчик подобный, скиньте, буду благодарен.

Comment: @nick_n_a, посмотри плз. Как и где Response отразить, если в js  создам ссылку и имитирую клик)

Comment: Правильность jquery - не знаю. На с# не вижу отдачи файла `Response.Clear();Response.Write();Response.End()`  я вам уже говорил вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за ответ. "Отдачи файла" нету потому что не понимаю где это отобразить. Хочу разобраться, алгоритм: `$.post` отправляет запрос с html на сервер, где создается _temp.pdf(_По сути сейчас у меня в темп папке пользователя лежит _temp.pdf_). Дальше в js, как вы мне говорили, я создаю ссылку и кликаю(снова на Download.aspx?) т.е. `Response.AddHeader(...filename= ` **тут что?** ) должен быть в  `Page_Load`, поправьте меня если я что-то недопонял.

Comment: Есть два случая. 1. когда вы можете передать файл, 2. когда вы можете отправить Stream или сгенерированые байты файла. Но в любом случае для отправки вы делаете Response.Clear, Response.AddHeader(  filename= имя скачаного файла) и допустим TransmitFile. Потом  'response.End(); ' после которого клиент примет файл.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вы меня извините такого тугого) Я сразу напишу что мне не понятно:  у меня файл temp.pdf **уже загружен** в папку "Темп" юзера, поэтому когда срабатывает click ссылки у меня в папке "Загрузки" создается пустой файл с моим именем.(_т.е. один в темп папке и один от response в загрузках_)

Comment: Скорее всего вы не отправили "тело" файла (т.е. не сделали Response.Write или TransmitFile). Я вашу библиотеку не пользовал, может вам другие подскажут как вам сделать, у меня пример выгрузки только для iTextSharp библиотеки есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо вам. Все получилось, как я хотел. Вы правы дело было в  `Response.TransmitFile(filePath);`. Вверху отразил как сделал выше, осталось проверки дописать.